# Cancel transforms, doesn't cancel bone pose

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints

Steps to reproduce:

1. In *Pose Mode*, press  <kbd>G</kbd> to move the IK target bone (in the video: the ring around the wrist)
2. Move the bone, but instead of applying the transform, press <kbd>Right Click</kbd> to cancel the transform

The armature doesn't fully move back to its previous pose.
To move the bones back to where they were, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>G</kbd> to reset the pose.

[Video example, where I show it happen 3 times, from different angles](https://www.veed.io/view/16190d3d-4fab-491c-a6c7-954b3100bb53)

Bone Constraints used, that may cause this:

- *IK*
- *Limit distance* (to prevent the hand to be too far away from the body)
- *Copy rotation* (wrist copies the IK Target bone's rotation)
- *Stretch to* (shoulder has an additional bone to make it look smoother)

I have tried deleting bones/constraints, but I wasn't able to remove this behaviour.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: You probably have a dependency loop in the armature that you need to fix.  This is typically from parenting the IK target or pole target to a bone involved in the IK chain, but it can be from constraints or drivers as well.

Comment: @Nathan Yes! That was my issue, thanks a lot for reminding me :)

Answer (score 0):

My IK target had the wrist as parent. Thus creating a dependency loop!
Thank you @Nathan.